# Polars: aggregating a subset of rows

Tags: python, python-polars

Suppose I have a data set with a group column, subgroup column, and value column:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(dict(
    grp = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    subgroup = ['x', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'y'],
    value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
))

┌─────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ grp ┆ subgroup ┆ value │
│ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ str      ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ A   ┆ x        ┆ 1     │
│ A   ┆ x        ┆ 2     │
│ A   ┆ y        ┆ 3     │
│ B   ┆ x        ┆ 4     │
│ B   ┆ x        ┆ 5     │
│ B   ┆ y        ┆ 6     │
└─────┴──────────┴───────┘
```

I'd like to calculate the mean `value` for each `group`, and also calculate the mean of the values where `subgroup` is "x". In polars, the most succinct way I've found to do this is:

```
(
    df
    .groupby(pl.col('grp'))
    .agg(
        pl.col('value').mean().alias('mean_all'),
        pl.when(pl.col('subgroup') == 'x').then(pl.col('value')).mean().alias('mean_x')
    )
)

┌─────┬──────────┬────────┐
│ grp ┆ mean_all ┆ mean_x │
│ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---    │
│ str ┆ f64      ┆ f64    │
╞═════╪══════════╪════════╡
│ A   ┆ 2.0      ┆ 1.5    │
│ B   ┆ 5.0      ┆ 4.5    │
└─────┴──────────┴────────┘
```

This works fine, but the call to `when...then` inside `agg` produces a warning about this not being a valid aggregation (even though the chain is finished with `mean`). Is there a more idiomatic or elegant way to perform this operation from inside a polars chain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter within the groupby to select subgroup 'x'.

```
(
    df
    .groupby(pl.col('grp'), maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        pl.col('value').mean().alias('mean_all'),
        pl.col("value").filter(pl.col("subgroup") == "x").mean().alias("mean_x")
    )
)
```

This produces

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬──────────┬────────┐
│ grp ┆ mean_all ┆ mean_x │
│ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---    │
│ str ┆ f64      ┆ f64    │
╞═════╪══════════╪════════╡
│ A   ┆ 2.0      ┆ 1.5    │
│ B   ┆ 5.0      ┆ 4.5    │
└─────┴──────────┴────────┘
```